# Наибольшая возрастающая подпоследовательность быстрее, чем за O(n log(n))

Tags: алгоритм

Есть классическая задача о поиске наибольшей возрастающей подпоследовательности данной последовательности. Мне известно несколько её решений, за O(n^2) и за O(n log(n)). Существуют ли более быстрые алгоритмы решения данной задачи? Существует ли теоретический нижний предел, больший, чем Omega(n)?

UPD: ищется именно подпоследовательность, а не подстрока. Я использую [это](http://bse.sci-lib.com/article090413.html) определение подпоследовательности, мне казалось, оно общепринято. Среди последовательности [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] [1, 4, 5] является подпоследовательностью, но не [5, 3].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Статья на википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence) утверждает что для алгоритмов основанных на сравнении есть нижняя граница, т.к. там написано что n log2 n − n log2log2 n + O(n) сравнений оптимально с точностью до константы в O(n)

Comment: Википедия - не показатель.

Comment: Я видел упоминание этого факта в другой статье, но пока не могу найти исходной статьи

Comment: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V00-47GHHPF-5&_user=10&_coverDate=12%2F31%2F1975&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=23eb9c6d3e019a6ab53bd169d1d2a7e3&searchtype=a
В этой статье есть доказательство, но к ней нет открытого доступа

Comment: @winger Я заменил ссылку на название статьи.

Answer (score -1):

Одно из возможных решений. Если я не ошибаюсь в оценке алгоритмов, то решение будет за O(n)

```
int lcmis(char *str, int len) {
    int maxlen = -1;
    int thislen = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        if (str[i-1] < str[i]){
            ++thislen;
            if(thislen > maxlen)
                maxlen = thislen;
        }else {
            thislen = 0;
        }
    }
    return ++maxlen;
}
```

Comment: Боюсь, что вы ошибаетесь в определении слова "подпоследовательность". Подпоследовательность может и не являться подстрокой (то есть, её элементы не обязательно идут подряд в исходной последовательности). Например, в последовательности "abcde" "ace" — подпоследовательность, а "cd" — подстрока и подпоследовательность. Ваш код ищет наибольшую возрастающую подстроку.

Comment: Мне кажется, что ответ верен. Подстрока - это тоже самое, что и подпоследовательность, если последовательность состоит из букв. Наибольшая возрастающая подпоследовательность - это такая последовательность, в которой каждый следующий элемент больше предыдущего, при этом элементы исходной последовательности не меняются местами. То, что Вы предлагаете, это другая задача, в которой необходимо составить возрастающую последовательность наибольшей длины из заданного алфавита (исходная последовательность).

Comment: Коллеги, вы про разные вещи говорите. Вам нужно четко определить, что вы понимаете под термином "подпоследовательность".

Comment: Непрерывная последовательность элементов исходного множества.

Comment: Мы действительно говорим про разные вещи. См. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence#Substring_vs._subsequence